# Git clone very slow on my hosted Bitbucket server

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, bitbucket-server

I have a very big project I would like to start versioning with Git in order to start working with a small team. This is my first time ever using Git.

I installed Bitbucket server on a machine running Windows 8 and did an initial commit + push, which took some time because I have close to 100k files that sum up to 41gb or so. I did use .gitignore to bring the size down to that because it's closer to 60gb normally. That went well. Note that on the server, with compression, the pack file only takes 21gb, which is awesome.

The problem is now I'm trying to download the project on a remote machine, as in not on the same local network, and I'm getting download speeds of 60kb/s when I have an upload of 10mbps so I should be hitting speeds close to 1mb/s. The ping between the remote and the server is 90ms as it is overseas. Transfer rate seems to be fine on both sides with a speedtest and also file sharing on Skype (I know, not really a benchmark) is reasonably fast, what would be expected with a 10mbps upload.

I checked the server while I was trying to clone and disk usage is flat at 0, network usage is almost 0 and CPU usage is also very low, no core is over 25% usage.

From all the "solutions" I found on the web, the most common one seemed to be to create a local user instead of running under an admin account, but the recent Bitbucket installer seems to have created an account by itself and is running under this account, or so I would believe.

I will appreciate any and all help I can get, been trying to solve this for two days now. Thank you.

Comment: Just noticed an insane amount of hard faults per second, but physical memory is not even half used. I remember reading about some page file settings in Bitbucket, I'll check that again.

Comment: Page file settings were in fact webpage settings for the web interface of Bitbucket. I noticed the processes with a lot of hard faults are all the same command line: "git pack-objects --revs --thin --stdout --delta-base-offset" and they're all using a bit of CPU and doing some 3mb/s disk read. I killed all 3 and all Git processes dissapeared. Retried cloning and 4 processes spawn and the hard faults start flowing in again. The computer has 8gb of RAM and 5.4gb of it is on standby. 1000 hard faults per second. Upload is always exactly 68kb/s.

Answer (score 1):

just restart all your network devices (or reset them if possible) like your modems, routers, hotspots and whatever you are using to get connected to internet.

This worked for me.

I was also facing the same issue, everything else was getting good speed except bitbucket, but it is solved when I restarted my mobile (I was using mobile's internet using hotspot)

Comment: I no longer have this issue due to change of hardware but if you look at the comments on my own issue, it looked like a problem on the server itself

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same problem so I have tried with [Sorucetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/).

You can install the Sorucetree from above link then open and Copy your repository and add files using this [link](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/copy-your-repository-and-add-files/)